# React native ffmpeg producing unplayable hevc videos that still have audio

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg, ffmpegkit

I have a react native application that is attempting to transcode users videos so they are in a format both platforms can natively playback, we are doing it on device for now as we don't want to incur the API costs till we have a stable user base. I have a few questions and let me preface them with my ffmpeg knowledge is not the best and mostly cobbled together.

1. Why does the following code produce videos that are unplayable but still have audio.

```js
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      await FFmpegKit.execute(`-i ${path} -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -y ${outputPath}`);
} else {
      await FFmpegKit.execute(`-i ${path} -c:v hevc_omx -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -y ${outputPath}`);
}
```

2. Is there a better set of commands to run for 1080p videos that will be played back on both platforms?

I am getting ffmpeg into the app using https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit and am using the `min-gpl` distribution. If I set the commands to use their h264 alternatives for the codec (`h264_videotoolbox` & `h264_omx`) it produces working files but I was hoping to use hevc to minimize the file sizes.

### Update - Solved

The `-tag:v hvc1` needed to be added so that Apple players can play the HEVC content.

Comment: Need to see logs. Add `-report` to both command strings and share report files.

Comment: I guess you could also ask this on video production or superuser, as more dedicated for the ffmpeg related stuff (if it's not strictly linked to the library implementation). Just pass the commands that don't work as you expect.

Comment: @Gyan here is a gist of the output logs I was able to gather. The `-report` flag throws permission errors so I gathered the log output. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't see any link to gist

Comment: @Gyan that is my fault. Here is the link: https://gist.github.com/martincalvert/047b41c474b71b4caa246b562921f3b1

Comment: Try adding `-tag:v hvc1` after the encoder and check.

Comment: @Gyan that was in fact the thing needed. Found somewhere deep in ffmpeg/hevc documentation about that being required for Apple video players. Thanks!