React-Native FFmpeg-kit VideoCompress command not working
I'm Using FFmpeg-kit's React-Native Kit
And I want to encode H264 to HEVC.
But the Videotoolbox in ios not working
I use  "ffmpeg-kit-react-native": "^6.0.2"
And here is my Code
        // hevc_videotoolbox
        await FFmpegKit.execute(`-i ${videoUri} -c:v hevc_videotoolbox  -c:a aac -tag:v hvc1 -movflags +faststart -y ${outputUri}`);
      } else {
        await FFmpegKit.execute(`-i ${videoUri} -c:v hevc_omx -c:a aac -tag:v hvc1 -movflags +faststart -y ${outputUri}`);
      }

But I got the error follwed like this
 LOG    libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
 LOG    libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
 LOG    libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
 LOG    libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
 LOG    libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
 LOG    libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
 LOG    libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
 LOG  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 
 LOG    Metadata:
 LOG      major_brand     :
 LOG  mp42
 LOG  
 LOG      minor_version   :
 LOG  1
 LOG  
 LOG      compatible_brands:
 LOG  isommp41mp42
 LOG  
 LOG      creation_time   :
 LOG  2024-08-29T02:42:24.000000Z
 LOG  
 LOG    Duration:
 LOG  00:00:23.10
 LOG  , start:
 LOG  0.000000
 LOG  , bitrate:
 LOG  1223 kb/s
 LOG  
 LOG    Stream #0:0
 LOG  [0x1]
 LOG  (und)
 LOG  : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1220 kb/s
 LOG  ,
 LOG  30 fps,
 LOG  30 tbr,
 LOG  600 tbn
 LOG   (default)
 LOG  
 LOG      Metadata:
 LOG        creation_time   :
 LOG  2024-08-29T02:42:24.000000Z
 LOG  
 LOG        handler_name    :
 LOG  Core Media Video
 LOG  
 LOG        vendor_id       :
 LOG  [0][0][0][0]
 LOG  
 LOG  Stream mapping:
 LOG    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
 LOG   (h264 (native) -> hevc (hevc_videotoolbox))
 LOG  
 LOG  Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 LOG  [hevc_videotoolbox @ 0x11af89120] Error encoding frame: -12905
 LOG  [hevc_videotoolbox @ 0x11af89120] popping: -542398533
 LOG  [vost#0:0/hevc_videotoolbox @ 0x11af88e50] Error initializing output stream: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
 LOG  Conversion failed!

How can I fix this error?
I read the
stack overflow

Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

2.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77734601/react-native-ffmpeg-producing-unplayable-hevc-videos-that-still-have-audio
But that links doesn't work for me
I want to compress video's compressing with react-native on ios and android for reducing server cost

I have a small problem I am trying to work with this same package but regarding the audio conversion issue, when I try to convert a file with m4a extension to mp3 it tells me that it is not possible to convert the file because the getLogLevel is null and I don't know how to solve it.
I hope a prompt response if someone knows how to solve this problem.
